# Fork errors with GNU Make

Tags: linux, makefile, operating-system

```
glibc: install step
/bin/sh: 2: Cannot fork
make[3428]: *** [Makefile:12: install] Error 2
make[3427]: *** [Makefile:12: install] Error 2
make[3426]: *** [Makefile:12: install] Error 2
make[3425]: *** [Makefile:12: install] Error 2
```

I'm getting this error when installing glibc, it's a part of my package build system. http://91.229.143.168:6500/job/55 rest of the log on the CI. https://github.com/ExpidusOS/builder/tree/redesign this is the builder. It's failing with https://github.com/ExpidusOS/packages/blob/master/source/glibc/pkg.mk this package's install step which is defined in https://github.com/ExpidusOS/packages/blob/master/builder/pkg-autotools.mk#L40. Does anyone know how to fix this? I did extensive testing, changing the ulimits didn't work. Inside Docker it has issues, even with the `--ulimit` flag. It has that error outside of Docker as well. I hope you guys will look through my code and try seeing what exactly is this issue. I am sick and tired of this issue holding back my distro's development.

Comment: Even before glibc fails you have this error on your build which you should check.

`tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
extract: failed to extract linux-5.5.2.tar.xz`

Comment: @crm That only happens on the CI, locally running the builder shows that does not happen.

Comment: Another thing that I've noticed is that on your build the error reported occurs in line 51 of pkg.mk and this makefile only has 49 lines. Moreover, have you tried to increase the maximum number of processes you can have on your system?

Comment: @CRM I have tried increasing the max number of processes, look at the build script.

Comment: The output of the build is offline.

Comment: @CRM I'm transitioning to Jenkins bc Abstruse was having issues with commits not pulling.